# Best practices to return entities with navigation properties as JSON in MVC with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC application with EntityFramework.
I want to return an instance of an entity with navigation properties as JsonResult, for example, a Customer instance, where it has a navigation property to a list of orders.

I am wondering what is the best way to do it:

- Declare a new DTO/Model View class to "flattern" the entity, but it seems the redundant information of Customer is stored in each DTO/View Model.
- Return as it is, then process it at client side. I don't like this approach as I need to do extra processing at client side which can be hard to debug. Also there's a risk of circular reference if I have a Customer navigation property at the Order entity.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is the second one: have the data returned as nested lists.
But you should not expand the navigation property all the time, and in each method/endpoint you should define and be explicit of which property to expand (to avoid the circular references problem you mentioned plus other performance issues).
Say you have a Customer object that has Orders as properties, if you need it to be returned you go like:

```
return context.Users.Include(b => b.Orders).ToList();
```

and If you don't need the orders in a separate end point you can just return the customers.

Comment: Thanks. I will go for this option.

Answer (score 1):

In large projects, I think the best way is to create a DTO to serialize your data as a JSON that will represent best the needs of the consumer. Even if the class have the same fields. As the project evolutes, more programmers putting their hands on the code, this is way better to give maintenance.